# Bitwise and in Amazon Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column in a Redshift database with bitmasks stored as ints. I want a way to find out if a particular bit (say, 32) is set. Redshift has `bit_and`, which would be great, except that it's only an aggregate function! So, you can't do `bit_and(column, 32)`.

I'd also be comfortable hacking this by casting the int to a char that was a binary representation and using `substring`. However, it doesn't look like there's a way to do that cast either.

`value & 32` should be just as simple as `value + 32`, but apparently not in Redshift. Any ideas?

Input:

```
le_column
35
2
```

Desired output:

```
column_has_32_set
1
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And... apparently, Redshift supports the standard `&`, they just don't document it (although they do document shift left and shift right?).

```
select
    le_column & 32
from
    le_table
```

Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OPERATOR_SYMBOLS.html

Comment: Thanks! The AWS Documentation has now been updated with the `&` operator.

Comment: Great! Could you also add the `|` (bitwise or) operator?